# Pass LINQ anomyous type results like a collection of property bags to a ASP.NET 5 MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, expando

I've searched around and people talk about using ExpandDo with dynamic, but I haven't been able to figure it out how to do this with a collection returned from a LINQ query.

I'm doing an inner join on my database between 2 tables (student and enrollments)

```
    var innerJoin =
        from e in db.Enrollments
        join s in db.Student on e.StudentID equals s.StudentID
        select new { Student= s.Name , Course = e.CourseID };
```

I've tried

```
dynamic model = innerJoin.ToList().ToExpando();

return View(model)
```

and I have

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>
```

at the top of my View.cshtml

but that gives this error when I try navigating to the controller in the web application:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]'. ''

I also tried:

```
   dynamic model = innerJoin.ToList();

    return View(model);
```

but then in my view (.cshtml file) I

```
    @foreach (dynamic item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.Raw(item.Course)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

it'll barf on the @Html.Raw line with

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   App_Web_index.cshtml.1bbec3a6.jtomobws.dll but was not handled in user
>   code

Ideally I'd like to make it a one liner. In my view I'm hoping to be able to iterate over a collection of property bags, and extract the Student and Course fields. So my property bag would contain properties Student and Course, and they'd be a collection of them. I've looked at many similar posts, but none have done this

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Do not use `dynamic`! Create a view model with properties `Student` and `Course`.

Comment: Thanks, you're probably right, and I see that advice alot. Regardless, I'm  interested in how to actually just get this working using dynamic, for learning's sake.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

I assume that `innerJoin.ToList().ToExpando();` converts the list of your anonymous objects returned from the join into Expando object and not to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. If you want to get List of dynamic objects you can use something like:

```
var innerJoin = from e in db.Enrollments
                join s in db.Student on e.StudentID equals s.StudentID
                select e;


var model = new List<dynamic>();
foreach(var l in innerJoin)
{
    dynamic temp = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    temp.Student = l.StudentID;
    temp.Course = l.CourseID;
    model.Add(temp);
}
```

This will work for `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>` model

[Here is the example for working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i9lLtk)

**Although I really advise you to use strongly typed models. By using dynamic objects you basically giving up on most of the advantages of [statically typed languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859186/why-is-c-sharp-statically-typed).**

Comment: Thanks alot, but now I'm getting Error CS0117 'ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Student' and the same for Course when I try to build