# Is C# statically typed or mostly statically typed?

Tags: c#

I'm reading [JoeDuffy](http://joeduffyblog.com/) book where he said: `C# is a (mostly) statically typed.`

Most of the articles and books I’ve read that describe C# as a strongly typed language are effectively using “strongly typed” to mean statically typed.

Where is the truth? What does `mostly` mean? (perhaps referring to very few features that step outside of the CLR's type-safety?)

Comment: Here is the truth: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/10/15/is-c-a-strongly-typed-or-a-weakly-typed-language/

Comment: Perhaps referring to the `dynamic` keyword?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/859186/447156

Comment: @SonerGönül Thanks for the link to Eric Lippert's blog!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most obvious non-statically typed part of C# is the `dynamic` keyword. A variable declared as `dynamic` defers type-related checks until runtime, so the following code is legal:

```
dynamic x = "a string";
x = 7;
x.NonExistingMethod();
```

Other parts of C# (including the `var` keyword) are statically typed. People sometimes confuse `var` with the keyword in JavaScript, but what `var` in C# does is *type inference*. Still statically typed, only less explicit.

Comment: `int[] a = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }; Console.WriteLine(a[3]);`

Why I can build this code successfully?

Comment: I think that overflowing a buffer or indexing into an arbitrary location of system memory are just not possible

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko why wouldn't you be able to? What part do you expect to fail? the way I understand it, indexers in C# are basically just method calls. The array type exposes an indexer that accepts an `int` argument. 3 is a valid `int`, so there's nothing fishy going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Statically typed programming languages do type checking `(the process of verifying and enforcing the constraints of types`) at compile-time as opposed to run-time. Dynamically typed programming languages do type checking at run-time as opposed to Compile-time.

Strong/Weak typing is about how strictly types are distinguished (e.g. whether the language tries to do implicit conversion from strings to numbers).

Simply put it this way: in a statically typed language the type is static, meaning once you set a variable to a type, you CANNOT change it.

The main advantage here is that all kinds of checking can be done by the compiler, and therefore a lot of stupid bugs are caught at a very early stage.

A language is dynamically typed if the type of a variable is interpreted at run-time. This means that you as a programmer can write a little quicker because you do not have to specify type every-time. Example: Perl, Ruby, Python

Most scripting languages have this feature as there is no compiler to do static type-checking anyway, but you may find yourself searching for a bug that is due to the interpreter misinterpreting the type of a variable

Comment: Can you answer to the main question? What does mostly mean?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko  In C# 3.0 and later you can use the "var" keyword instead of the type name in many cases

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan the `var` keyword does not let go of static typing. try wrtiting `var x = "hi"; x = 1;` and see if the compiler complains. the `dynamic` keyword does however.

Comment: Please do incorporate what actually applies to C# into this answer.