# Enumerated values compared to the left and right sides identified as inconsistent

Tags: c#, winforms, boolean

I am creating a windows application written in C#.  I created a class `Palette` which defines an enumerated type of property: `direction {up, down, right, left}`.  Inside another class of type `Form1` I created an instance `p` of `Palette`.

Here is a simplified version:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Palette
    {
        public Direction _direction
        {
            set { this._direction = value; }
            get { return this._direction; }
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Palette p;
        public enum Direction
        {
            Left, Right, Up, Down
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            p = new Palette { _direction = Direction.Up };
        }
    }
```

Then i think, p.direction should also be an enumerated type, is not it?

My software does not think that because I use it to compare 
p.direction! = Direction.up.

It thinks the type on the left is `Palette._direction`. The right type is enum.

How can i do it?

Comment: Could you post the code in question? It's hard for me to understand what the issue is exactly.

Comment: Please add punctuation. I'm not going to struggle to read the question.

Comment: well I really want to post my code. but the website just don't allow me .

Comment: "well I really want to post my code" Please do. You should be able to put the text right in the question. Indent each line with 4 spaces to make the markdown engine recognize it as a code block.

Comment: because every time I add the picture, it said my post had some text which is similar to code. I tried to change it ,but i failed.

Comment: Yeah, please don't post code as a picture. That limits its searchability for future visitors that might be encountering a similar issue.

Comment: Can you post the _exact_ error message?   Is it possible that you have `Direction` defined more than once in your code?

Comment: @renesmith - I rewrote your question to make it clearer.  Can you confirm that my changes are correct?  For the future, you're much more likely to get helpful answers if your question contains a [mcve] -- a **minimal** example of code that fully demonstrates your problem.

Comment: thanks ,it is more clear ,but 不是很正确, Because there should also be a Direction of enum type which is defined by me in the Palette class

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I define Direction in both Palette and Form1. I want to show the picture, it show the error more clearly than i told you , but i just cannot . the website don't allow. Sorry

Comment: @renesmith - code and error messages must be included in your question as text, not as images.  See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for why.  In addition, you might want to take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips on how to ask questions that are likely to get answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code does not compile as expected is that you have declared the enum `Direction` to be a [nested type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types), nested inside the outer type `Form1`, while the referring type `Palette` is *not* so nested.  A nested type is a type defined within a class or struct.  When referred to by code within that outer type, its name can be used directly.  I.e. inside `Form1` you can refer to your enum by simply doing `Direction.Up`.  But *outside* the containing type it is necessary to use the full name of the nested type, which is `Form1.Direction`.

Thus, to fix your problem, you could:

1. Move `Direction` outside of `Form1`, making it a top-level type in the `WindowsFormsApplication1` namespace.

   This is recommended if you are going to use `Palette` in multiple different forms.
2. Make both `Palette` and `Direction` be nested types inside `Form1`.

   This is recommended if `Palette` is only used inside `Form1` or needs access to access private or protected members of `Form1`.
3. In `Palette` use the full name for `Direction`:

   ```
   public Form1.Direction _direction { get; set; }
   ```

   While this will compile it is not recommended as it is awkward and inconsistent.

Incidentally, you have an unrelated problem in your code, namely that your `_direction` property has an infinite recursion.  You should modify it to be an [auto-implemented property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) or make the manually created backing field have a different name than the property.

Thus a fixed version of your code might look like:

```
public class Palette
{
    Direction _direction;

    public Direction Direction
    {
        set { this._direction = value; }
        get { return this._direction; }
    }
}

public enum Direction
{
    Left, Right, Up, Down
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Palette p;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p = new Palette { Direction = Direction.Up };
    }
}
```

Since your full code apparently compiles, you may have some other type `WindowsFormsApplication1.Direction` whose name would conflict with that of your nested `Direction` type if you were to move it out of `Form1`.  If so, and you want to keep `Palette` outside of `Form`, your options are:

1. In the event they are actually duplicates, simply eliminate the inner nested type.
2. If they are not duplicates, rename the `Direction` enum to something else, say `DirectionType`.

Comment: 其实是事实 I  define Direction in Form1 and Palette.

Comment: @renesmith - Well that would be your mistake.  You need to define it in only one place.  Your original question did not show that by the way.  In the future, when asking a question please try to include a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.  In this case your question did not show both definitions for `Direction`.

Comment: oh, but why it is wrong to define it in two class?

Comment: @renesmith - because c# is [nominally typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) rather than [structurally typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).  The two enum types `WindowsFormsApplication1.Palette.Direction` and `WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Direction` are differently named so they are different types.  The fact that their contents are identical is irrelevant.

Comment: nested type and non-nested type cannot compile? even if they are both enum type?  And if  I want to compare it , i need to be sure they are the same kind of enum type if  I want to judge if they are the same, right?

Comment: @renesmith - You can't just assign one to the other because they're not the same type, and c# is a [statically and strongly typed language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859186/why-is-c-sharp-statically-typed).  Remove the duplication.  Otherwise you have to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1818131).

Comment: 分配？我没有这样做。你是说创建一个新变量吗？总之，由于他们是在两个类中创建的枚举变量，因此不是同一种类型，从而不能进行比较，我的理解对吗？

Comment: @renesmith - well your code didn't compile and was incomplete so who knows, I took my best guess as to what you were doing.  If you were passing an argument of type `WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.Direction` to the `Palette` constructor that expects an argument of the type `indowsFormsApplication1.Palette.Direction` then it's the same thing.  And since it appears I wasn't able to guess your actual problem from your code fragments I'll be deleting this answer; good luck!

Comment: you don't need to do it.  I just a beginner of C#. So I think i am trying to understand you answer. thanks you!

Comment: @renesmith - then if the question is answered please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).

Comment: and there is another thing I am confused. "_direction property has an infinite recursion." I don't understand. and if I change it into  public Direction Direction
    {
        set { this._direction = value; }
        get { return this._direction; }
    } I don't know if there will be ambiguity of Direction. Because it can be a type and also can be a member, right? when i changed it as you told me ,it showed WindowsFormsApplication1.Palette.Direction and WindowsFormsApplication1.Palette.Direction contains ambiguity